# How is it possible that the (program) source file in Chrome developer tool is hidden?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When you open the chrome developper tool and that you go in the "Source" tab.
Normally you can see all the source (html, css, js) of the website you'r currently on.

Chrome create a "(program)" file that contains base js of the current page

Do anyone knows why the (program) would not be here ?

Because I have some javascript that chrome put in that file and when I do a Search in All File (Ctrl + Shift + F) it doesnt search in the (program) source because it is not in the treeview.

Thanks !

Comment: Does it appear on reload?

Comment: No it does not. The "(Program)" is not always visisble on all website but it is on the website i'm working on.